# "of" in "slow of the mind" "slow of heart"

Tags: phrases, prepositions

> Stonecrusher considered both of them to be **slow of the mind** except in fights. ([book](https://books.google.com/books?id=njj11Jfj9gIC&pg=PT53&dq=%22slow%20of%20the%20mind%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2-In8q7n_AhU-ATQIHdPeDT0Q6AF6BAgTEAI))

This use of the preposition "of" sounds nonidiomatic to me, but I wonder if it is a dated use. This sentence from a book isn't the only instance where I have seen it used like this. I also encountered "slow of the mind" a few times before. I recall similar phrasing in the Bible:

> Then he said unto them, O fools, and **slow of heart** to believe all that the prophets have spoken: (Luke 24:25, KJV)

> And he said to them, “O foolish ones, and **slow of heart** to believe all that the prophets have spoken! (Luke 24:25, ESV)

What is this use of "of"? Does it still have currency in British English or any other English varieties?

Comment: It's just a way of saying an adjective and giving its range. Saying someone is slow of mind is like saying they have a slow mind. Prepositions like _of_ don't have any meanings; they just show up in the machinery, like gears and washers.

Comment: The *of* is normal, but here should not be a *the*: *slow of mind, slow of heart*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use od "of" in this expression and others (for instance "[slow of wit](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow%20of%20the%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)", and "[slow of step](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow%20of%20step%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)") must be very rare. The research "[slow of the](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow%20of%20the%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" gives only false positives.

[image]

[slow of mind](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow%20of%20mind%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

It is best to consider as unidiomatic the use of "the" in all such expressions.

*Added by
[user 66974](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/608652/of-in-slow-of-the-mind-slow-of-heart/608655?noredirect=1#comment1538805_608655)*

[slow of speech](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22slow%20of%20speech%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)